# how to scroll page left and right with user touch iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scroll

in an Iphone app, I am in need of building a page that scroll left and right by user touch.
Much like the built-in weather application already existing in every iphone/ipod, but I am not interested in having a page control.

The left and right scrolling is like a sort of history browsing. Moving the finger left and right, I can show a new panel with exactly the same effect of the weather application. In addition, the panel can have different height, depending on how many information are in it.

Can you point out the best way to achieve that ? Which controller to use, components ecc...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UIScrollView` with `pagingEnabled = YES`. You can just omit the page control, it is completely independent of the paging scroll view.

Comment: thanks, I have managed to implement it using pagingEnabled. Do you know if it's possible, to automatically scroll and preselect the UIScrollViewer to a specific point (in this case a page) ?

Comment: Just set the scrollView's contentOffset property to the appropriate value.